# Inspinia Theme breaks bootstrap data target collapse?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, themes

We are using inspinia theme and we have one (huge) issue with it.
When we click on the „burger menu“ to open the navigation (navbar-toggle) the navigation opens, closes and then opens again.
This also happens when we simply add the standard bootstrap example to one of our pages.

Here is an example that you can try out

```
<a  class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">  simple collapsible</a> 
<div id="demo" class="collapse in">THIS<br>IS<br>A<br>TEST</div>
```

It seems as if the theme breaks the standard bootstrap mechanism here.

The problem also appears if I use the standard jQuery collapse and on my desktop (Mac OS) it only happens on Safari. Firefox and Chrome work fine.

**I know that most probably all of the people reading this won´t know the inspinia theme, but maybe someone has experienced a similar issue with bootstrap collapse ?**

Comment: Just contact theme creators, not here ;)

Comment: yea, I did ... not expecting too much help though ;)

Comment: Did you try to remove `in` class from that div? And add `collapsed` class to `a` element.

Comment: nothing changed. it opens and then it closes and then it opens again